# Changing vertical position of UIBarButtonItem on iOS 8.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

Here is my navigation bar

[image: Image link]

I had a problem about changing vertical position of Settings `UIBarButtonItem` on my navigation bar. I would like to move the button item "Settings" down

Here is my code

```
 UIBarButtonItem *settingsItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
 self.navItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingsItem; 
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0,-10) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I had tried it again and again. It seemed that it's not work

Could anyone suggest me how to move the button item "Settings" down ?

Comment: what is the code, where you add settings button to the NavigationBar Item??

Comment: This is my code

[code]
UIBarButtonItem *settingsItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
    self.navItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingsItem;
[/code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily add a Custom Button to your NavigationBarItem, Here is the way,

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; //create custom Button
    [button setTitle:@"Settings" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:179.0/255.0 green:40.0/255.0 blue:18.0/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20); //Button frame
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourCustomSelectorHere) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //Add action method to the button here
    UIView *backButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 63, 33)];
    backButtonView.bounds = CGRectOffset(backButtonView.bounds, -14, -7);
    [backButtonView addSubview:button];
    UIBarButtonItem *barBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView: backButtonView]; //set button as UIBarButtonItem
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barBtnItem; //set barBtnItem to rightBarButtonItem
```

By changing `backButtonView.bounds` values you can change the origin of the Button

Comment: I tried to use your way, but it did not work like my way before

Comment: I would like to move the "settings" down, but when I had tried your way, it did not change.

Comment: I don't know. I would like to move it to be in the same level with the title "iRestaurant"

Comment: Now, The button is at the right position, but when I click it, it doesn't blink / flash like a normal button. I'm confused

Answer (score 1):

Cited from apple's documentation on `UIAppearance` protocol

> iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t
>   change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window.

So if your code of setting UIBarButtonItem's appearance is after the navigationItem assignment code. It won't work